# Show that operator is not adjoint

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to prove that the following linear product is not adjoint. Let V be the vector space of all polynomials in the complex field. Define the inner product as $$\langle f(x) , g(x)\rangle = \sum_{n=0}^ \infty \frac{1}{n!} \overline{f^{(n)}(0)}g^{(n)}(0) $$
 and the linear operator $$L(f(x))=f(x+1)+f(x-1)$$ How to prove that this is not adjoint? My thinking was to first assume that the adjoint exist, and then plug it in. This gives me $$\sum_{n=0}^ \infty \frac{1}{n!} \overline{f^{(n)}(0)}g^{(n)}(1) + \sum_{n=0}^ \infty \frac{1}{n!} \overline{f^{(n)}(0)}g^{(n)}(-1) $$
How do I proceed from here, or am I completely off?

Comment: What do you mean by 'not adjoint'?

Comment: @copper.hat The exact phrasing is: "Show that L does not have an adjoint operator L(dagger)"

Comment: Is $L$ continuous?

Comment: @copper.hat It doesn't say anything about whether L is continous or not

Comment: I meant for you to show that it is continuous :-).